# SQL Write ID from one table to another

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm brand new to SQL, and am working with a postgreSQL database. I currently have two tables one called patterns the other called pattern_analysis. Below are the contents of each table.

**patterns**

- pattern_id
- pattern

**pattern_analysis**

- post_id
- post_index
- pattern
- pattern_id

What I am currently doing is a string search on a bunch of different posts, and if it matches a given pattern then write that to the database. I have it writing the post_id, post_index, and pattern to the pattern_analysis table, but how to I get the pattern_id from the patterns table into the pattern_analysis table?

Edit: I am interfacing with the database using python 2.6 and psycopg2. I'm not sure if that changes anything but I am assuming it doesn't.

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Answer (score 1):

A quick update statement should do the trick:

UPDATE pa SET pa.pattern_id = p.pattern_id
FROM pattern_analysis PA JOIN patterns P ON PA.pattern = P.pattern

Full disclosure, not tested and this is the syntax I used in MS-SQL so might be a little different in postgre.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your SQL insert code looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO pattern_analysis (post_id,post_index,pattern) VALUES (x,xx,xxx)
```

Where 'x', 'xx', 'xxx' are the values you are writing in to the database. You could use a sub query to get the pattern_id from the patterns table at the time you do this INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO pattern_analysis (post_id,post_index,pattern,pattern_id) 
VALUES (x,xx,xxx,(SELECT pattern_id FROM patterns p WHERE p.pattern = xxx))
```